# Mirroring on some bones happens on all three axes at once

Tags: bones, pose-mode

I downloaded a model from the internet, and since the bones were broken, I had to re-position them myself. They aren't mirrored perfectly, since the armature was oriented wrong when I first imported it and I didn't realize it until later. There was one thing I couldn't figure out, though. When using X-axis pose mirroring, some bones seem to be mirroring on all three axes at once.

Here's the thigh bones exhibiting the expected behavior. Mirroring along the X-axis does just that - the pose is mirrored along the X-axis and nothing else.
[image]

Here's what I'm getting with the broken bones. Mirroring along the X-axis also mirrors along the Y and Z axes.

[image]

And don't even get me started on what's happening with the foot bones. It looks like the rotation is getting rotated in some arbitrary direction and amount, if that makes any sense?

[image]

I've tried un-parenting and re-parenting all the bones, and I've tried resetting the weird roll values on them. Neither helped. What is going on here?

Here's the rig:
[image]

Comment: Nuke level fix: select all bones in pose and "clear pose constraints" operation, then select one side of bones in edit mode and "symmetrize" operation.  Not sure that's all necessary, because we don't have the rig.

Comment: @Nathan I just tried that, and it didn't change anything. Don't think it had any constraints in the first place. I don't know how to upload the rig, or I would.

Comment: You can post a file at https://blend-exchange.com/ and edit your question to include the code it gives you.

Comment: @Nathan I uploaded the rig and edited it into the post.

Comment: Your axis of symmetry is your armature X axis.  You've built your armature with its X axis pointing forward.

Comment: @Nathan Rotating the bones so that the Y axis points forward didn't do anything to the broken bones, and just made the ones that actually worked stop working.